# Android custom layout wrap content

Tags: android

I am implementing custom layout. 
I put ImageViews to my layout and in onMeasure() method call all children child.measure(w, h)

Everything works fine instead of wrap_content behavior.
Views behave like they are match_parent and are full screen size instead of wrap content.

When I want to make view to be wrap_content doing this

```
if (boxSize == MyBox.RATIO_MEASURE) {
                spec = MeasureSpec.AT_MOST;
                size = containerSize;
```

code:

```
@Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {

            View v = getChildAt(i);
                    // custom layout logic
            MyBox box = getBox(v);

            int width = getMeasuredSpec(box.getWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
            int height = getMeasuredSpec(box.getHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);

            v.measure(width, height);
        }
    }

    private int getMeasuredSpec(float boxSize, int containerSpec) {

        int containerSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(containerSpec);

        int spec;
        int size;

        if (boxSize == MyBox.RATIO_MEASURE) {
            spec = MeasureSpec.AT_MOST;
            size = containerSize;
        } else if (boxSize == 1) {
            spec = MeasureSpec.AT_MOST;
            size = containerSize;
        } else {
            spec = MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;
            size = (int) (MyBox.isScreenDependent(boxSize)
                    ? containerSize * boxSize
                    : boxSize);

        }

        return MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(size, spec);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hrm.... this seems tricky b/c you are doing it from inside Java.

I think the magical class that you want is LayoutParams

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#MATCH_PARENT

```
    int WRAP_CONTENT= -2;
    LayoutParams params= new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT);
    ImageView bNext_Word = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.myimage);
mImage.setLayoutParams( params);
```

Comment: I don't care about view's layout params, I want to measure it depend on my custom lobic box class. Layout params is set to determine how big view should be. Actually view have wrap_content already set it in xml. LayoutParams are for Layouts. BoxLayout is layout and it doesn't depend on LayoutParams